# Extracting data from specific columns of numpy array for each row

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to obtain the value corresponding to column b[i] for each row i in A

Can I do this without using the for loop?

```
A = np.array([[35, 2, 23, 22], [44, 21, 15, 4], [44, 21, 15, 4], [37, 4, 17, 41], [33, 4, 4, 18], [35, 2, 23, 22]])
b = np.array([0,1,1,2,3,0])
C = zeros(len(b),1)
for i in range(6):
    C[i] = A[i][b[i]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to sequentially index the rows of `A`, you can index with **`np.arange(len(A))`** in addition to `b` to get your desired output:

```
A[np.arange(len(A)), b]

# array([35, 21, 21, 17, 18, 35])
```

Showing how this works:

```
#               A              np.arange(len(A))    b
array([[35,  2, 23, 22],                     [0,    0]
       [44, 21, 15,  4],                     [1,    1]
       [44, 21, 15,  4],                     [2,    1]
       [37,  4, 17, 41],                     [3,    2]
       [33,  4,  4, 18],                     [4,    3]
       [35,  2, 23, 22]])                    [5,    0]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
A[:,b].diagonal()
Out[133]: array([35, 21, 21, 17, 18, 35])
```